# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime while converting from Arab Standard Time to datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to convert String into DateTime. Everything is correct but don't know why I am getting this error;

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

```
string  dtf = hdnFromDate.Value;
```

(While debugging I can see dtf value is `Sun Dec 13 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Arab Standard Time))` and I am trying to convert into DateTime But no success
I am converting in this way

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dtf, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

I also try like this

```
DateTime dt= DateTime.ParseExact(dtf, 
                  "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'K '(Arab Standard Time)'", 
                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your second format [works just fine](https://rextester.com/UBQF20924) for me. What _exactly_ is the problem that you're having with it?

Comment: What exactly is populating that hidden value with that string? Can you change it to use a more sensible format?

Comment: If you want to keep the timezone info use `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(..` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference to [DateTime.ParseExact Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-5.0)

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
> DateTime equivalent. The format of the string representation must
> match a specified format exactly or an exception is thrown.

So your datetime string should like this otherwise you will get exception

`Mon Dec 14 2020 14:42:46 GMT+08:00 (Arab Standard Time)`

or

`Mon Dec 14 2020 14:42:46 GMT+0800 (Arab Standard Time)`

You can try this to get what kind of string you need

```
Console.WriteLine(
   DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd MMM dd yyyy HH: mm:ss 'GMT'K '(Arab Standard Time)'", 
   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
);
```

If your string have whitespace li

`Mon Dec 14 2020 14:   42:46 GMT+08:00 (Arab Standard Time)`

Yoo can try

```
Console.WriteLine(
   DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd MMM dd yyyy HH: mm:ss 'GMT'K '(Arab Standard Time)'", 
   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
   DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces)
);
```

Comment: `K` should work fine whether or not the timezone information has a colon (i.e., `GMT+08:00` vs `GMT+0800`). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618459/troubles-parsing-datetime-from-string#comment15384882_11618668) and the demo in my comment above.

Comment: Ok, add it to the answer